# Send email based on condition

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, conditional-statements, sendmail

I have defined an array of numbers as a variable and would like to send an email if a number within that array is >= 45. However, when I run the code it sends an email regardless if my condition has been met. How do I get it to send an email only when the condition has been met? See the below script as reference:

```
function sendEmail1(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName('Dewar ID');
var sheet5 = ss.getSheetByName('Notification Settings');
var email_listing = sheet5.getRange(5,1).getValue();
var subject = sheet5.getRange(3,2).getValue();
var message = sheet5.getRange(3,3).getValue();
var todaysDate = sheet4.getRange(1,8).getValue();
var daysPastService = sheet4.getRange("E3:E60").getValues();

if(daysPastService >= 45)
{return true;}
GmailApp.sendEmail(email_listing, subject, message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendEmail1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName('Dewar ID');
  var sheet5 = ss.getSheetByName('Notification Settings');
  var email_listing = sheet5.getRange(5, 1).getDisplayValue();
  var subject = sheet5.getRange(3, 2).getDisplayValue();
  var message = sheet5.getRange(3, 3).getDisplayValue();
  var o = sheet4.getRange("E3:E60").getValues().flat().filter(e => e >= 45).filter(e => e);
  if (o && o.length > 0) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email_listing, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: It still sends an email regardless if the condition is met or not. What is the `e` meant for in your script?

Comment: It can't you must not have implemented it properly

Comment: Look at the filter method for Arrays in a Javascript reference and you'll see what the e is.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your "GmailApp.sendEmail(email_listing, subject, message);" is outside of the conditional.  And, your daysPastService variable is an array, so you need to iterate through each cell.

Try ...

```
var greaterThan45 = false;
for(var i=0; i<daysPastService.length; i++) {
  if(daysPastService[i] >= 45) {
    greaterThan45 = true;
  }
}
if(daysPastService) {  //if it's been set to true, because any of the cells were >= 45
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email_listing, subject, message);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: When I try this method even though the program runs, no email is being sent even when the condition is met. However, I tried setting a particular cell as a variable (e.g.  `var dewar1 = sheet4.getRange(3,5).getValues();` ) and the condition works to send the email. Its seems that when I have an array it can not distinguish which number is >= the condition. Is there a way for it to identify the condition within the array or is it just a single cell?

Comment: You're correct; I missed that your variable (daysPastservice) was an array, so I hadn't iterated through it.  I've updated this with the iteration to check if any of the cells are >= 45.